# pandas create column as lagged difference of two other columns grouped by key

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe (`df`)

```
                       AmountNeeded         AmountAvailable
Source Target                                              
1      2                      290.0                   600.0
       4                      300.0                   600.0
       6                      200.0                   600.0
3      2                      290.0                   450.0
       5                      100.0                   450.0 
7      8                        0.0                   500.0
```

I would like to compute the **remaining availability per source**:

```
                       AmountNeeded    AmountAvailable       RemainingAvailability
Source Target                                              
1      2                      290.0             600.0                          600
       4                      300.0             600.0                          310
       6                      200.0             600.0                           10
3      2                      290.0             450.0                          450
       5                      100.0             450.0                          160
7      8                        0.0             500.0                          500
```

So if a `Source` appears more than once, I need to subtract the sum of lagged values of `AmountNeeded` for that particular `Source`.
If we take `Source 1` and `Target 4` the remaining amount should be `AmountAvailable-AmountNeeded(previous_row) = 600 - 290 = 310`
If we move to `Source 1` and `Target 6` this will be: `600 - (290+300) = 10`.
This also be computed as `RemainingAvailability - AmountNeeded = 310 - 300 = 10`

I tried to use different combinations of groupby and diff but without much success.

Comment: What is the logic you are using to calculate `RemainingAvailability`?

Comment: @Rajnishkumar Hi, as I wrote in the title and in the body of the question, I need to compute the remaining availability **per source**. So if a Source appears more than once, I need to subtract the sum of lagged values of `AmountNeeded` for that particular `source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with helper Series created by lambda function with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and cumulative sum [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = df.groupby(level=0)['AmountNeeded'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
df['RemainingAvailability'] = df['AmountAvailable'].sub(s)
print (df)

               AmountNeeded  AmountAvailable  RemainingAvailability
Source Target                                                      
1      2              290.0            600.0                  600.0
       4              300.0            600.0                  310.0
       6              200.0            600.0                   10.0
3      2              290.0            450.0                  450.0
       5              100.0            450.0                  160.0
7      8                0.0            500.0                  500.0
```